# Can you destroy the Star Destroyer in the last level of Shadows of the Empire (N64/PC)?

Tags: shadows-of-the-empire

For some reason I just thought of the last level of Shadows of the Empire where you have to destroy the Skyhook. There's a Star Destroyer in the level as well, which seemed indestructible. Is it possible to destroy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my findings, no, it cannot be destroyed.

From a Gamefaq [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/n64/198789-star-wars-shadows-of-the-empire/faqs/3303):

> Mission 10 (Skyhook Battle): Q: Can you destroy the Imperial Star
>   Destroyer on this mission? A: I don't think so. I have heard rumors of
>   people shooting it with missles and lasers for 55 minutes and getting 
>   it down to 99%, but I really doubt you can destroy it, and even if you
>   can, who is going to spend that kind of time to find out? Not me! :-)

And here is a [Gamefaqs forum discussion](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/198789-star-wars-shadows-of-the-empire/41474778)

> along time ago when I was 9 or something I almost killed it (had it to
>   3%) then I woke up :/
>
> i was so disappointed, I turned the game on and shot it for an hour
>   and so badly wanted to waste it but it stayed on 100%.
>
> so yeah, I do not think it can be done. I remember somebody saying
>   they shot it for 3 hours to get it to 99%, which is very doubtful but
>   even if it was true whose gunna go for 0%?